# Cannot resolve symbol 'context' in 'USING A PRELOADED SQLITE DATABASE WITH SQLITEOPENHELPER' example

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

I'm using this [class java](http://kdehairy.com/using-a-preloaded-sqlite-database-with-sqliteopenhelper/) to read db from assets folder and to copy to database folder.

In page link, it say:

> To Use it ...
>
> Just use it normally as you would use an ordinary SQLiteOpenHelper
>   object.
>
> Repository repo = Repository.getInstance( context );   SQLiteDatabase
>   db = repo.getWritableDatabase();   ...

but in simple new project wizard return error in context parameter.
Anyone can help me, please?

[image: cannot resolve symbol context]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using this class java to read db from assets folder and to copy to database folder.

I strongly recommend that you [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), as it is a more mature and tested solution.

> but in simple new projet wizard return error in context paramenter

The `Repository` constructor takes a `Context`. `Activity` inherits from `Context`. You are trying to use a `Repository` in a method of an `Activity`. Hence, replace `context` with `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Android activities inherit `Context` class, so you can do it as follows:

```
Repository.getInstance(this);
```